# differentiate between Cocoa touch app and Cocos2d app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I have an SDK for iOS apps. The SDK is used in Cocoa applications and Cocos2d applications. SDK also have a UIPageControl which works fine in Cocoa apps while it doesn't work correctly in Cocos2d apps. I want to figure out which app/platform is being using my SDK whether it's a Cocos2D or Cocoa. How can I do this in objective C?

Any help in this regard would be helpful.

Comment: Well, for one, what template did you choose when you created your project?

Comment: You're assuming the two SDKs are mutually exclusive, which is not the case. One can pretty freely mix Cocos2D and UIKit in a single app. Not to mention the rest of Cocoa, huge parts of which are being used by Cocos2D, too.

Comment: MDT ...I developed SDK with cocoa touch and it needs to be used in both platforms.

Comment: Ole ... I have only one SDK. I don't have two SDKs. I just use it into Cocoa and Cocos2D applications.

Comment: I'm not talking about your SDK. I'm talking about Cocos2D and Cocoa (Touch). They are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: To reiterate what Ole is saying in different terms: `UIPageControl` (and anything else from Cocoa Touch) can work just fine in apps also using Cocos2d. It will just take some extra work and understanding on your part to get things to behave like you expect.